# Is there a way to extend the functionality of the Github Copilot plugin for vs code?

Tags: typescript, listener, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I want to develop a vs-code plugin that extends the functionality of GitHub CoPilot. I want to listen to code completions and reward the user with points based on the length and content of the completions made with CoPilot. Is it possible to write a plugin that builds upon the original plugin, or do I have to use the OpenAI API to recreate the functionality of the plugin to add my Gamification elements?
Thanks a lot in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: _"add my Gamification elements"_ - oof. [MS did this once](https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2012/01/18/visual-studio-achievements-program-brings-gamification-to-development/), achievements like "copy paste your code 5 times" or "use this shortcut key 30 times" or "have 4000 lines of code in one file". It did not necessarily lead to better code, quite the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

It will be possible *only* if GitHub Copilot also exposes an API to other extensions. And, since GitHub Copilot is not an open source extension, you won't be able to look its source to find out.

In this case, I suggest you to ask them, opening an issue on their support channel.

If no API is exposed, you won't be able to develop your extension, unfortunately.

Hope this helps

Comment: As I answered below, this actually is possible: https://github.com/B00TK1D/copilot-api

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to use OpenAI Codex API

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do you think that?

Comment: The answer below explains it best, the API is not open for development

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could extend the functionality of Copilot: either modify the extension source code (for which I described an example of how to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78119075/7381479), or write your own plugin using Copilot's API.

Although Copilot does not have an official API, as others mentioned, their API is accesible publicly, and I have written an interface that allows you to use it.  As long as your extension can read the local copilot token, then your extension could seamlessly call GPT-4 and Codex without needing an API key of your own.  Here is the HTTP-based API interface that I wrote to demonstrate: https://github.com/B00TK1D/copilot-api